# Query goes in endless loop

Tags: php, mysql, loops

The following goes into an endless loop, meaning it just constantly shows the same record over and over and over again.

```
<?php
while ($rowr = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1")) {
    while($rowu = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE id = '".$rowr['uid']."'"))){
        while($rowc = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table3 WHERE id = '".$rowr['cid']."'"))){
    ?>
    <tr><td><?php echo $rowc['post']; ?></td><td><a href="other.php?id=<?php echo $rowu['id']; ?>"><?php echo $rowu['username']; ?></a></td><td><a href="this.php?p=d&i=<?php echo $rowr['id']; ?>"><font color="#FF0000">X</font></a></td></tr>
    <?php
        };
    };
};
?>
```

Why does that happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: that must hurt your database.. can't you simply fetch all tables first and then make a loop? upd: haven;t noticed that it's endless loop

Comment: Epic loop. There is something called JOIN.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are putting the mysql query in the `while` statement so every time it gets there it does the same query and shows the same first record, you are never advancing to the next record in the result set.

Personally I would combine all queries into one, but to show how you can solve your problem (the same applies to all loops):

```
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table3 WHERE id = '".$rowr['cid']."'");
while ($rowc = mysql_fetch_assoc($results))
{
  // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I do wonder why this happens, isn't it the same thing as what I did? I am kinda confused on that part.

Comment: @gdscei, it's not. `mysql_fetch_assoc` gets called _every time_ before one cycle starts whereas `mysql_query` gets called only _once_ before the loop. `mysql_fetch_assoc` just traverses the results received from the query, `mysql_query` actually gets the data from the db.

Comment: @gdscei No, it´s not the same because in your code the query qets executed every time the `while` condition is checked (once every time it loops), so every time it is checked, the database is queried, a new result-set is loaded and the first row is assigned to your variable.

Comment: I must say such behaviour is quite strange, but alright, thanks for the explainations.

Comment: @gdscei It´s not that strange, just follow the flow of the program: After the first iteration you return to the `while` statement, but instead of just fetching the second row like in my answer, you execute the query again and fetch a row, which is again the first row. And over and over.

Comment: I think I find it strange because I've always seen variables as simple replacements for the long code, but apparently it saves your query from going into a loop.

Comment: @gdscei, the point is that the _condition_ of `while` gets executed **every time** a new cycle is about to start. If you have just a variable there, just it's precomputed value gets recalled, it does not get computed again. That's a big difference. Often the difference between the correct behaviour and an endless loop.

Answer (score 2):

Simply because the query gets executed again every time the loop condition is checked. That means you'll always get the same result unless something changes in the database in the meantime.

You need something like this:

```
<?php
$res1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1");
while ($rowr = mysql_fetch_assoc($res1)) {

    $res2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE id = '".$rowr['uid']."'");
    while($rowu = mysql_fetch_assoc($res2)){

        $res3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table3 WHERE id = '".$rowr['cid']."'");
        while($rowc = mysql_fetch_assoc($res3)){
?>
    <tr><td><?php echo $rowc['post']; ?></td><td><a href="other.php?id=<?php echo $rowu['id']; ?>"><?php echo $rowu['username']; ?></a></td><td><a href="this.php?p=d&i=<?php echo $rowr['id']; ?>"><font color="#FF0000">X</font></a></td></tr>
<?php
        }
    }
}
?>
```

That's just to illustrate why it doesn't work. As others already noted, combining your queries into one using [**JOIN**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html) would be advisable.

Btw, you don't need a `;` after a `{}` block.

Answer (score 0):

Use joins and you can do it in one query.

[Mysql Join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

[Join Tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlleftjoin.php)

Comment: but they are related by uid and cid, no?

Answer (score 0):

You're re-executing the queries on each loop iteration, restarting the results from scratch.

You want something like this instead:

```
$resultR = mysql_query("... table1");
while($rowR = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultR)) {
    $resultU = mysql_query("... table2");
    while($rowU = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultU)) {
        etc...
    }
}
```

Of course, this is a highly inefficient construct. You end up running count($rowR) * count($rowU) * count($rowC) queries. Why not reformulate it as a join?